# Why is my JavaScript marquee glitching when it reaches the end and starts over?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a bidirectional marquee effect using a JavaScript class. It uses the CSS transform property making use of translate3d() to translate the wrapper left or right based on the class instance

```
    const moveReel = () => {
        if (this.direction === "left") {
          currentPosition -= this.speed;
          if (currentPosition < -totalWidth - 1) {
            currentPosition = 0;
          }
        } else {
          currentPosition += this.speed;
          if (currentPosition > 1) {
            currentPosition = -totalWidth;
          }
        }

        wrapper.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentPosition}px, 0, 0)`;
        requestAnimationFrame(moveReel);
      };
```

When the currentPosition value is set to 0, there is a glitch in the animation where the content blinks and glitters back 1 or 2 pixels

Here is the complete code

**Reeller JavaScript Class**

```
class Reeller {
  constructor(options) {
    this.containers = document.querySelectorAll(options.container);
    this.speed = options.speed || 1;
    this.direction = options.reversed ? "right" : "left"; // Default to left direction

    this.containers.forEach((container) => {
      let wrapper = container.querySelector(options.wrapper);
      let items = wrapper.querySelectorAll(options.itemSelector);
      // Calculate the width of a single item including margin
      const itemWidth =
        items[0].offsetWidth +
        parseFloat(getComputedStyle(items[0]).marginRight);

      // Calculate the total width of all items
      const totalWidth = itemWidth * items.length;

      // Clone the items and append them to the wrapper
      const cloneItems = [];
      let count = 10;
      while (count--) {
        for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
          const clonedItem = items[j].cloneNode(true);
          cloneItems.push(clonedItem);
          // prepend() dosent work it was a dumb idea
          wrapper.appendChild(clonedItem);
        }
      }

      // Set the width of the wrapper to fit all the items
      wrapper.style.width = totalWidth + "px";

      // Initialize the intersection observer to detect when the last cloned item is in the viewport
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (
            entry.isIntersecting &&
            entry.target === cloneItems[cloneItems.length - 1]
          ) {
            // Remove all the cloned items
            cloneItems.forEach((item) => item.remove());
            cloneItems.length = 0;

            // Reset the position of the wrapper to its original state
            wrapper.style.transform = `translate3d(${-totalWidth}px, 0, 0)`;
          }
        });
      });

      // Observe the last cloned item
      observer.observe(cloneItems[cloneItems.length - 1]);

      // Animate the wrapper
      let currentPosition = -totalWidth;
      const moveReel = () => {
        if (this.direction === "left") {
          currentPosition -= this.speed;
          if (currentPosition < -totalWidth - 1) {
            currentPosition = 0;
          }
        } else {
          currentPosition += this.speed;
          if (currentPosition > 1) {
            currentPosition = -totalWidth;
          }
        }

        wrapper.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentPosition}px, 0, 0)`;
        requestAnimationFrame(moveReel);
      };

      requestAnimationFrame(moveReel);
    });
  }
}
```

**And here is the HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .my__reel {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .my__reel__wrap {
        display: flex;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .my__reel__item {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 40px;
      }

      .h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: 200;
      }

      .my-reel-item-2 {
        background: rgb(222, 231, 255);
        padding: 5px 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- First marquee -->
    <div class="my__reel my-reel-1">
      <div class="my__reel__wrap my-reel-wrap-1">
        <div class="my__reel__item my-reel-item-1">
          <h1>REEEEEL</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second marquee, more noticeable on this one -->
    <div class="my__reel my-reel-2">
      <div class="my__reel__wrap my-reel-wrap-2">
        <div class="my__reel__item my-reel-item-2">
          <h1>REEEEEL</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="my__reel__item my-reel-item-2">
          <h1>WOW</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="my__reel__item my-reel-item-2">
          <h1>AHHHHHHH</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="reeller.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Reeller({
        container: ".my-reel-1",
        wrapper: ".my-reel-wrap-1",
        itemSelector: ".my-reel-item-1",
        speed: 0,
      });

      new Reeller({
        container: ".my-reel-2",
        wrapper: ".my-reel-wrap-2",
        itemSelector: ".my-reel-item-2",
        speed: 2,
        reversed: true,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried modifying the code by changing the currentPosition value to a small negative number, such as -0.1, instead of 0, but this did not solve the problem. I also tried adjusting the speed and easing options, but this did not help either the blinking is still there and when the speed is increased the glitch is very noticeable